# What is C++ Technical Specification?

Tags: c++, c++14, c++-concepts

Concepts-lite C++ (proposal N3701) feature is not included in C++1y standard, but it is said it will be published as Technical Specification. What does it exactly mean? Will it automatically become a standard feature in next C++ releases?

Comment: in short: it's a way for the committee to work more effectively. Focus groups can create Technical Specifications.

Comment: @KarolyHorvath but what does it mean to the *users* of C++?

Comment: @n.m.: nothing that you should worry about. it means the language&libraries will evolve more rapidly.

Comment: If the doc describing the C++ standard would be a program, a technical specification could be considered as a patch/addon.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I usually don't like copy-paste answer's, but I think it is pretty well explained [here](http://isocpp.org/std/status):

> Starting in 2012, the committee has transitioned to a “decoupled”
>   model where major pieces of work progress independently from the
>   Standard itself and can be delivered asynchronously in the form of
>   Technical Specifications (TS’s) that are separate from the main
>   Standard and can later be incorporated into the Standard. With
>   releases targeting 2014 onward, we are focusing in particular on
>   producing new C++ standard libraries; to participate, see the Call for
>   Proposals and instructions for how to Submit a Proposal.
>
> This decoupled model allows the committee to deliver smaller pieces of
>   work in a faster and more predictable way. Decoupling enables this in
>   a number of ways, including that each TS’s work can progress at is own
>   speed, can be delivered sooner without waiting for the next Standard,
>   and can be delivered in a form that lets the community gain experience
>   with the feature and possibly adjust its design before it is formally
>   included in the actual Standard. Decoupling the work also allows the
>   Standard itself to be delivered on a more regular cadence with smaller
>   and more predictable “batches” of features, which helps compilers
>   track the Standard more closely and encourages different compilers to
>   add new features in a more consistent order.

What this means for users:

You will able to use any of these new features from a separate namespace which I believe will be `std::experimental::fundamentals_v1`*. Once these features are "fully-baked", they will be incorporated into the C++ standard and moved to the `std` namespace.

*: Although it looks like `fundamentals_v1` will be an inline namespace, so you can just prepend `std::experimental`.

Comment: I thought they were going to follow the same `tr` pattern (e.g. `std::tr3::whatever`).  Is that not the case?

Comment: @ZacHowland: Here is the [latest draft](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2014/n3848.html#general.namespaces) which explains it.