# Dynamic control over execution policy type for C++

Tags: c++, g++, c++17, std, c++20

I noticed in c++ documents a class called [execution_policy](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2017/n4698.html#parallel.execpol.dynamic), which could be used for dynamic control of parallelism type or event turning it off, currently, I am using GCC 9.2 and I can't find this class or related header. Also noticed [here](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2016/p0024r2.html) there is changelog for removing it. 
Why class this useful need to be removed. Is there a replacement or an experimental version that I could use with GCC. If not what is the efficient way of implementing it?

Comment: The technical specifications are experimental and are sort of [Try-Outs](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/try-out) for future inclusion in the Standard Library. Sometimes they don't live up to expectations once folks have experimented with them in the wild and can be removed for any number of reasons. Sorta-duplicate: [What is C++ Technical Specification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21342077/what-is-c-technical-specification)

Comment: @user4581301 but `ExecutionPolicy` is part of the standard, for example [`25.7.11`](http://eel.is/c++draft/alg.sorting#sort) (sorting) specifies an overload taking `ExecutionPolicy&&`. Does that mean that a function, while introduced by the standard, may be required to rely on using `experimental` namespace? If yes, does this mean that `experimental` is standardised? If not, why the standard specifies something that relies on completely non-standard behaviours?

Comment: @Fureeish No. `ExecutionPolicy` != `execution_policy`. `ExecutionPolicy` is a concept; it's just a template parameter name. `execution_policy` is an actual type.

Comment: @Justin thank you for correcting me - that was an oversight on my part. However, I believe the point still stands, doesn't it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dynamic `execution_policy` was deferred past C++17 (and 20) because it would require committing to an ABI for representing the various policies.  (With only templates consuming them, any client contains its own copy appropriate to whatever representation it happens to use.)  It is possible to [choose policies dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52975114/8586227), but you can’t make your own execution policy objects that could be passed to the standard algorithms (again, for future specification flexibility).